# Applying textures to 3D models

Tags: xna, textures, xna-4.0, models, 3d-meshes

I want to apply textures to a 3D `Model` in XNA 4.

Whatever I saw on the internet was to apply the textures in the modeling tool and then load the model (*.fbx) into XNA.
Is it possible to load the `Model` into XNA game first and then apply the `Texture` into its `Meshes` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you have to set it to a shader which you draw your model with. If it is a hand-written shader then you have to set it tothe shader:

```
Texture2D texture;
Effect ef;
ef.Parameters["xTexture0"].SetValue(texture);
```

Specify a Texture in it and a sampler, for example:

```
Texture xTexture0;
sampler TextureSampler0 = sampler_state { 
                                        texture = <xTexture0>; 
                                        magfilter = anisotropic; 
                                        minfilter = anisotropic; 
                                        mipfilter = linear; 
                                        AddressU = wrap; 
                                        AddressV = wrap;
                                       };
```

Then sample it:

```
float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler0, coordinates);
//coordinates is a float2 for a 2D texture, but float3 for a cubemap
```

If you want to use it with an XNA effect (Basiceffect for example) then you just have to set it before drawing to that effect:

```
Texture2D texture;
BasicEffect ef;
ef.Texture=texture;
ef.TextureEnabled=true;
```

Please note that normally you will have to have texture coordinates specified in your model file to use textures this way, except if you are using projective texturing.

Comment: Assigning texture properties in `BasicEffect` worked for me. I guess UV coordinates must me specified in the `Model` itself. Is it a good idea to apply texture in a plain model or have the texture in the model itself before loading it into XNA?

Comment: You don't have the texture *in* the model before loading but the link of the texture so when loading the model, XNA loads the texture with it like you would.